# select attribute with divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make some divs which can be selected. (also multiple selected) So i searched in the internet for any possibilities and i found this:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

There it would be able to select multipe element,  but is an select and i want to  use divs. Also it would be wonderfull when i select a div, that its backgroud would change.

Is there a result for it?

Comment: toggle some class and apply css to that

Comment: there are lots of plugins and scripts that do this already ...let google be your friend

Comment: what should i google?

Comment: So you want a "custom select dropdown'? and why not native select dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your divs element and apply css to it, this is an example using jquery.

```js
$('.child').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
```

```css
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 4px
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.child:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.child.selected {
    background-color: crimson;
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child selected"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```